# Giving Command to particular USB Port

Tags: command-line, usb, ubuntu-touch

I want to execute **adb** command from terminal. But I am unable to use `adb -s <ANDROID_ID> *command*` since all the devices have same **ANDROID_ID**.
Is it possible to execute `adb` command on particular USB Port.

Output of `lspci -nn | grep USB`:

```
*00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)*
```

Now I want to fire adb command only on USB Port **00:14.0**

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The `-s` switch is for serial numbers not devices ID. The correct way is using `adb devices` then get the list of devices and from there you select the serial number you want to manipulate:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554  device
emulator-5556  device
emulator-5558  device

$ adb -s emulator-5556 install helloWorld.apk
```

Source http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#commandsummary